# VMWare - how can I access a "shared" "partition" from within a VM?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, hard-drive

I'll be using a VMWare VM, and from within the VM I need to be able to save files to a directory which exists outside of the VM. I'm running VMWare NOT inside of a host OS though. Is this possible, and what is the correct terminology?

Comment: We need to know more about your environment to answer this question -- Where are you trying to put these files? (the VMWare hypervisor host? Another (physical or virtual) machine (if so, what OS is the target running)? -- Don't worry about terminology: Clearly describe your goals and we can tell you what it's called :)

Answer (score 11):

Remove `VM`, `virtual`, and `VMWare` from your question, since they don't matter, and essentially you get:

> How do I save files from one machine to another?

You do this any number of ways. NFS, CIFS/SMB, SCP, FTP, etc.

Answer (score 5):

VMware's [HGFS](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html) is a mechanism to do this, but as you've correctly surmised, you can't use it on ESXi.

Mapping virtual media to a VM via the VMware vSphere client is one option for a temporary file move, but it's more likely that you'll need to set up network connectivity and an NFS or SMB share to get the kind of shared storage that you're looking for.